# Which method is best for computing the Matthews correlation coefficient (MCC) values for an unrelated data set?

Tags: statistics

Which method is best suited for computing the Matthews correlation coefficient (MCC) values for an unrelated data set?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure what is meant by "best method" here, but given a [confusion matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix) the computation should be straightforward.  In Python:

```py
import math

# tp is true positives, fn is false negatives, etc
mcc = (tp*tn - fp*fn) / math.sqrt( (tp + fp)*(tp + fn)*(tn + fp)*(tn + fn) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is correct, however in your formula you might want to also consider those cases where any of the four sums in the denominator is zero; in such cases, the denominator can be arbitrarily set to one.

For the sake of completeness, I'm adding R code below (the original code can be found [here](https://www.kaggle.com/c/bosch-production-line-performance/forums/t/23363/compute-mcc-in-r/139524))

```
mcc <- function (actual, predicted)
{
  # handles zero denominator and verflow error on large-ish products in denominator.
  #
  # actual = vector of true outcomes, 1 = Positive, 0 = Negative
  # predicted = vector of predicted outcomes, 1 = Positive, 0 = Negative
  # function returns MCC

  TP <- sum(actual == 1 & predicted == 1)
  TN <- sum(actual == 0 & predicted == 0)
  FP <- sum(actual == 0 & predicted == 1)
  FN <- sum(actual == 1 & predicted == 0)

  sum1 <- TP+FP; sum2 <-TP+FN ; sum3 <-TN+FP ; sum4 <- TN+FN;
  denom <- as.double(sum1)*sum2*sum3*sum4 # as.double to avoid overflow error on large products

  if (any(sum1==0, sum2==0, sum3==0, sum4==0)) {
    denom <- 1
  }

  mcc <- ((TP*TN)-(FP*FN)) / sqrt(denom)
  return(mcc)
}
```